# React Native: Maintain focus on textInput in header while switching nested tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-instantsearch

I'm facing a problem while implementing a search experience.

I have a react native screen that has a header with a SearchBar. When I focus on the TextInput of the SearchBar, another screen is shown with three nested, top-positioned tabs that indicate the top results and 2 sub groups of results.

I would like to keep my focus on the TextInput in the SearchBar while still being able to tap the tabs, showing the different query results.

I am using react-native-router-flux for routing and react-native-search-box as SearchBar.

```
   <Scene key="challengeStack" icon={ChallengesIcon}>
    <Scene key="search" currentUserId={currentUser.id} navBar={SearchHeader} headerMode="none">
      <Scene
        key="searchResultsTabs"
        tabs
        swipeEnabled
        tabBarPosition="top"
        upperCaseLabel={false}
        indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#36c99d' }}
        showLabel
        inactiveTintColor="#343942"
        activeTintColor="#343942"
      >
        <Scene key="searchResults" tabBarLabel="Top" component={SearchResults} />
        <Scene
          key="peopleResults"
          tabBarLabel="People"
          currentUserId={currentUser.id}
          component={Feed}
        />
        <Scene
          key="challengeResults"
          tabBarLabel="Challenges"
          currentUserId={currentUser.id}
          component={Feed}
        />
      </Scene>
    </Scene>
```

And my SearchBar:

```
 <View
  style={{
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomColor: 'gainsboro',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
  }}
>
  <Search
    backgroundColor="white"
    titleCancelColor="#343942"
    placeholderExpandedMargin={30}
    onChangeText={text => onChangetext(text)}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    keyboardDismissOnSubmit={false}
    onFocus={() => Actions.replace('searchResults')}
    onCancel={() => Actions.replace('categories')}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture?

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov I wasnt able to implement this myself but it is exact what Instagram provides as search experience: 
[Example](https://i.imgur.com/ld2bYGC.png)